# Why does AJAX is so long?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

Hi all i'm trying to compile and send some forms to a php file, but i noticed that it's very slow, even if in PHP i var_dump only the POST values, it takes the same time if i run with my correct functions.
Maybe the code is wrong, this is what i'm trying to do:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
        $("#button").css("border","2px solid blue");
        var total_forms = $("input[name=total_forms]").val();
         $.ajax( {
        type: "POST",
        url: "<? echo "myurl.php";?>",
        data: {delete : 1}, //before sending my forms i need to run another function that delete some items in mySQL DB
        success: function(data) {
        for(var i = 0; i < total_forms; i++){
            var string_ok = "#form_number_";
            string_ok = string_ok.concat(i);
            var dataString = $(string_ok).serialize();
             $.ajax( {
        type: "POST",
        url: "echo "myUrl.php;"",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data); //it's a bit faster, only a bit
            $("#mydiv").append(data); //it's a bit slower
        }
            });
        }
        }
            });
    });
```

I forget to say that i'm running it on MAMP in a macbook with 8GB RAM and SSD with only 10GB free, maybe my PC is the problem, IDK..

it takes about 4minutes to compile, send to PHP and stamp datas for 500forms

this is an example of dataString that i send:

```
prd_number=1259&prd_max_number=1763&old_prd_id=0&prd_action=true&title=INFORMAT%20G1X85A%23A80&title_check=true&old_title_text=&new_image_url=&old_image_url=&is_mech=&image_check=true&new_cat=Informatica%2CINFORMAT&category=true&new_price_text=222.04&price=true&new_sku_text=888182658918&oth=true&ncw=negat&stwe=testing&mark_text=INFORMAT_G1X85A%23A80&check_two=true&other_sto=table&var2=true&elemt=&weight=true&qt=3&qslow=true&clients=Norman%2Cli&taking=true&setting=normal&vars_set=true
```

i noticed that if i console.log(dataString), the console first stamps all dataString logs, and then starts to print each php response.

Comment: about 35inputs type hidden and 4/5 checkboxes @JaromandaX

Comment: i also noticed that when the query takes much time to runs(first ajax call)
the second ajax call crashes after 100 forms and continue to console.log() nothing @JaromandaX

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135640/discussion-between-jack-usti-and-jaromanda-x).

Comment: Why? i'm trying to understand what i don't know

Comment: You are submitting 500 forms?

Comment: Telling by your example, you send about 250MB of payload to the server + probably another 100MB for the request header. If that's the amount of data per user and send-click you should use a CDN or a cloud service to handle the load. I doubt that a single server (even a big commercial one) could handle that kind of load. Your regular apache can/does handle about 100 open connections at a time. Each of your user creates 500 commections with a single click, and blocks the whole server for 4 minutes (according to you).

Comment: how can i do, are there any example? @Thomas

Comment: how can you do, what? First of all, why are there 500 forms in your page? What are you building here? My pages rarely have more than 2 forms on them, and one of them is usually a search box. Then why do you need to send the content of all of these to the server? Couldn't you just send the diff? And you should batch that into a single request, or at least size it down to a reasonable amount like 5-10 requests instead of 500.

Comment: So, can we move to a chat? so i'll explain?

Comment: sure, but sadly, I think we have to spam the comments a bit till SO tells us to move to a chat

Comment: yes i think so...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135680/discussion-between-jack-usti-and-thomas).

Answer (score 0):

- Are you sending the data locally? Like is your php server running locally or is it hosted somewhere?
- How much data are on the forms?
- Also your code is sending an ajax request in the for loop. so You have a nested ajax call going on, one on every iteration of your loop. Thats of course going to be slower, is there a way you can refactor this to be one ajax request? Basically your making an ajax request, waiting for that response to come back, for looping, then sending another every time you iterate. Seems a little convoluted.

Comment: Yes, i'm using localhost.

I don't know how to check how much datas are on the forms, i don't think much 'cause there are only strings not too large,

i did in this way because i want a dynamic response for each data updated, so i have "item 1 of 100 updated" "item 2..." and so on..

Comment: i Updated my answer with more details @Ryan